# Custom ssrs expression not working when trying to connect to SQL Server 2008 servers

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on a ssrs report where I am using a custom data source i.e. I am using ssrs expression `="data source=" & Parameters!ServerName.Value & ";initial catalog=master;integrated security=sspi"` to use multiple connections from selected parameter to connect to that particular server.
I am able to connect to SQL Server 2012 and above. But below 2012 versions are not connecting.
I tried integrated security as true and false and yet it didn't connect.

Comment: which version of report builder or vs you are using?

Comment: 2014 report builder

Comment: Have you tried to remotely connect to the server using other tools (like SSMS)?

Comment: For example, you have a report created using ssrs 2014 that is attempting to connect to a 2008 ssrs database?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to connect 2008 servers from ssrs 2014 report server and I am using dynamic ssrs Express to connect to database